# What is the storage_full directory? Can I delete it or clean it up?

Tags: nexus

My company has a nexus installation that grew to a rather huge size on disk, thus I am in the process of cleaning it up. While doing so, I found a directory called `storage_full` in the `sonatype-work/nexus` directory, adjacent to the `storage` folder, which is not listed in [the nexus directories documentation](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/install-sect-dirs.html). Google finds nothing either. The folder is rather large and seems to be similar to `storage` in structure.

Questions:

- What is the use of this directory?
- Can I delete it, or clean it up? I'd rather not use trial and error to find out if it's important as any downtime of the service is unacceptable.

The nexus version is 2.11.2-03, but AFAIK it has been repeatedly updated and was running in the same work directory since about 2011 - could it be that this folder was left over from an older version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nexus has never had a directory called "storage_full" as part of it's setup, so I'm not sure what this is.  Check to see of the local storage location of any of your repositories has been overridden to point to that location.

Comment: Thanks, I just checked and it's not configured as storage folder in any repository. Which is weird, because spot checking a few libs I found that it in some case contained _newer_ versions of libraries than the actual repostiory, meaning it's probably not an old backup. As the old admin of the system left the company a while ago, I guess I'll never find out who created it and why...